# Unable to connect to internet, Connection Refused

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a massive problem. I am unable to connect to a Java server-socket from the android emulator. I have got the log and code:

**I am using a version 2.1 (Eclair) emulator to run my android application.**

```
System.out.println("Sup");
try{
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 26753);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println("e:ask");
    out.println("p:pass");
    out.println("EOF");
    socket.close();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Logcat errors:

```
05-02 21:35:41.986: I/System.out(276): Sup
05-02 21:35:41.996: W/System.err(276): java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:26753 - Connection refused
05-02 21:35:41.996: W/System.err(276):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:255)
05-02 21:35:41.996: W/System.err(276):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
05-02 21:35:41.996: W/System.err(276):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:780)
05-02 21:35:41.996: W/System.err(276):  at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:192)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:256)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:220)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at TestClass.skytheventure.TestClass.onClick(TestClass.java:38)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-02 21:35:42.006: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-02 21:35:42.016: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 21:35:42.027: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 21:35:42.027: W/System.err(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-02 21:35:42.027: W/System.err(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-02 21:35:42.027: W/System.err(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do I need more permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the ip of the emulator. 10.0.2.2 is what you are looking for (the host the emulator is running on)

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure you put internet permission in your manifest file, and then make sure your host and port number are all correct, and lastly check that you have right to access that host+port.

Comment: I have the android permission in the manifest. Everything is correct, it just gives 'Connection refused'

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks to WarrenFaith